# UpdatePanel is not reflecting changes from partial postback when UpdatePanel div is relocated using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I am attempting to gradually transition a site that relies on update panels and ASP.NET controls to use a client-side paradigm. As one step in that process, I am attempting to recreate an update-panel-based modal and turn it into a client-side modal.

To do this, I am putting the content of this modal, which is an update panel with some child controls, in a hidden div when the page loads, and when the modal is opened, I `.detach()` the update panel from its hidden div and `.append` it to the content div of the new client-based modal.

However, after the update panel is detached and appended (but not before) partial postbacks triggered by its child controls no longer result in updated HTML being returned by ASP.NET. Instead, it appears that the original HTML for the update panel is being returned instead.

My question is, what difference does it make WHERE an update panel div is located on a page as long as all of its DOM events are still attached? Why would the update panel partial postback fail to result in updated HTML being returned simply because the update panel has been moved from its initial location in the document?

**Update:**

After doing some additional debugging, I found that when the update panel is in its original position, the `CreateChildControls()` method of the modal dialog control fires *before* a particular code-behind click handler responsible for updating the update panel. But after the update panel has been moved, the *click handler* fires before the `CreateChildControls()` method. After the `CreateChildControls()` method fires, the content child control for the modal dialog control is set to invisible, which results in the content of that modal not being updated.

This raises two additional questions. When `CreateChildControls()` is invoked in the second scenario, the content container control is set to Visible, but after calling the `.Add()` method of the custom control's `Controls` property, the content container control is set to invisible. Why might that be?

The second question is, why would changing the location of the update panel in the DOM change the order of execution in the code behind such that the click handler fires before the `CreateChildControls()` method?

Comment: There migth be some other components that use or relate the updatePanel you moved and sometime, not being inside te same div makes the difference, i don't know if i understood your question correctly, but i'll tell you that, updatePanel is a very sensitive control and everytime i moved one, i had problems...

Comment: I added an update. I was able to get the content of the modal to display after the update panel had been moved, but it required me to use the immediate window to set the visibility of the content container child control to true because after calling the `.Add()` method to add the content container to the modal control's `Controls` collection, the visibility becomes false.

Comment: So it solved it ? It was the visibility ?

Comment: Not exactly. I was able to get the content to display, but now I'm trying to figure out why calling `Controls.Add(contentContainer)` in the modal dialog custom control results in contentContainer.Visible becoming false. More importantly, I'm also trying to figure out why the order of execution of the code-behind is different after I move the update panel on the client side.

Comment: This can happen if a parent control pass down is attributes to the child control, but about the code behind, i would say that you have javascript function that postBack or something, but i can't be sure